# How can I write this query in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm new in linq and want to write this query:

```
var query = from p in behzad.rptost
            where p.date.substring(0, 4) == "1395"
            -->in this calc sum=p.price_moavaq+price_year
            select p;
```

How can I write that query?

Comment: If you explain your data move then we will be able to help. what is `price_year`? can you provide some example data and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I assume you are trying to sum up the `price_moavaq` field per year.
Furthermore, by the use of the `substring` I guess your `date` field isn't of `DateTime` type but just a `string`.

So you need to use a `groupby`:

```
var query = from p in behzad.rptost
            group p by p.date.substring(0, 4) into grouping
            select new { Year = p.Key, Sum = p.Sum(x => x.price_moavaq);
```

In the case that your date field is of `DateTime` type then just use `.Year`:

```
var query = from p in behzad.rptost
            group p by p.date.Year into grouping
            select new { Year = p.Key, Sum = p.Sum(x => x.price_moavaq);
```